# Is it possible to open Modern UI apps on a second display?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, internet-explorer-10, extended-desktop

It seems like when opening the Modern UI version of IE from the Start screen, it will only open on the main display. Afterwards, I don't know how to move it to the second display, since <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> don't work for Modern UI apps. Is this possible or do I need to go to desktop mode and do it that way?

Comment: What about Win+Shift+Left/Right arrow?

Comment: In the Windows 8.1 on my machine today, if I hover the mouse over the top of a window, a Windows 7-like title bar appears. That can be dragged to another screen as one would do in Windows 7.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move the Metro environment to another display.

You can also put your mouse in the lower left corner of the screen you want it to open on and click on the mini Metro UI image that pops up.

Comment: This moves the whole "world of metro" to the other screen. I don't think it's possible to have the start screen coming up on screen 1 and a metro app up on screen 2.

Comment: @KateGregory That's correct, Metro cannot take up more than one screen. If you have a multimonitor setup, the other screens will display the traditional desktop.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but an answer nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally: what an AWFUL design decision. Talk about disincentivizing.

Comment: Talked to the Metro Design guy from Microsoft and he explained to me they really wanted to do it better, but that Multi-Monitor support for Metro didn't make it. Sai not too many people use more than one screen and since Metro needs to work flawlessly on tablets etc, this wasn't high prio for this release. When they do it, they want to do it right. That might include multiple monitor support where a tablet and a secondary display (another pc or a TV for example) can share screens as well.

Comment: This is now possible in Windows 8 Release Preview, btw.

Comment: @RafaelRivera how?

Comment: @nhinkle In the original revision of this post, there was mention of Consumer Preview hence my comment. It has now been edited.

Comment: Win-PgUp/Dn didn't work for me on my Surface Pro 3 (Win8.1), but the click on the lower left Windows icon did.

Answer (score 7):

I found that by placing the cursor (using a mouse, haven't tried this on a tablet) at the top of the window of the Metro App it becomes a hand icon.

[image]

At this point:

- Drag the window down a bit, until it shrinks in size.
- Now drag the window to another monitor to move it to that monitor.

Comment: It does work on tablets, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can move apps between and around your screens.

When you press the <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, you move apps around your screen. When you press the <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>, you move the app from screen to screen.

If you're using a mouse, you can also grab the title bar and move the app where you want it. To see the title bar on a Windows Store app, move your mouse to the top of the app.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/how-connect-multiple-monitors

Answer (score 0):

I was still having problems getting metro apps to the second screen after reading this post. When I checked the display resolution of my second screen I realised I was not using the "recommended" settings at 1024x768 but a "higher" resolution at 1280x720.

Once I switched my second monitor to the recommended resolution the metro apps would then correctly move over to that screen using the Windows logo+shift+left/right arrow keys as suggested by other posters.

Hope this helps someone