# How do I change which monitor my Start Menu appears on in Windows 8?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 beta: Is it possible to open metro apps on a second display?](https://superuser.com/questions/422584/windows-8-beta-is-it-possible-to-open-metro-apps-on-a-second-display)

I have two monitors, and I've set my primary display to the one on my left. However, for some reason the Start Menu, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and any <del>Metro</del> Modern UI programs still open on my right monitor.

How can I change this? I've tried <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and such, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

All <del>Metro</del> Modern UI applications (and possibly other fullscreen applications) and the start menu can be moved to a different monitor using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Comment: Only the RTM version of Windows 8 as this ability. These multi-monitor improvements only were completed after the RTM was released.  Since Windows 8 has not been released I feel its important to point this out.